# Development Environment Setup Tips

Tags: installation, environment

Can anyone offer tips on how to setup the ideal windows development environment? Contemplating on moving to vmware or virtual box setup for development and keeping the development tools off of my main system but then think that would cause a headaches if I want to just try something really quick.

Just looking for suggestions from other developers on how they setup their development environment to achieve the maximum productivity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend VMWare or a similar Virtualization product. It saves so much time.

I setup a VMWare image with a clean Windows install all the development tools I needed, and I then made a copy of this. Now anytime I need a "clean" dev environment I can simply duplicate the VM Image and off I go!

It also means all my non-development files are seperate and are out of harms way.

And if I choose, I can take the VM file with me to another PC and have the same development environment.

Using a VM also lets you try stuff out without any harm. You can create a "snapshot" - run/perform some action, then easily revert back to the snapshot. Great for testing something over and over quite easily.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards. I have been playing with VirtualBox and it appears to run a lot fast than vmware but cloning is a littler harder. Without development tools installs on your main machine though do you find decreased productivity if you need to just "test" an idea out quickly?

Comment: I find that I can get the VM image up and running pretty quickly - I never feel that i'm waiting for it to start - and I can always do something else while its booting. So i've never had much of a problem with booting it up, testing something out, and then closing it down.

Comment: I will try that out then. Maybe it will make a difference when I offload all of the development tools I have loaded on my main machine. Just seems like there is a delay in launching the VM that I could just launch it locally instead. Thanks for your input!